# UITableView does not show full data table unless reloaded with rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I'm trying to make sense out of an old objective-C code from my predecessor and I am quite stumped on this problem.

We have a `DashboardView` class, and a `DashboardViewController` class which updates the former. `DashboardView` class has `UITableView *m_data_tbl` that shows the data in question.

on `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading` of `DashboardViewController`, it invokes `[m_dashboard_view setNeedsLayout]`, where `m_dashboard_view` is a member variable of `DashboardViewController`.

`setNeedsLayout` of `DashboardView` is implemented as follows:

```
- (void) setNeedsLayout {
    [self populateHeaderScrollView];
    [self populateData];
    [m_data_tbl reloadData];
}
```

where the first two functions populate the data and header scrolls.

The problem is that upon the first execution, only a part of the data is shown. Namely, the last two columns(the rightmost when scrolled) do not show at all. It is impossible to scroll to show the last two columns. **When the user rotates from the portraits to landscape does the last two columns appear.**

Needless to say, the following is the implementation of `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` of `DashboardController`:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
        /* animation codes are omitted */
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape) {
        [m_dashboard_view adjustForType:0];
    }
    else {
        [m_dashboard_view adjustForType:1];
    }
```

`adjustForType` is implemented as:

```
-(void)adjustForType:(NSInteger)type
{
    if(type == 0)
    {
        m_data_tbl.frame = CGRectMake
        m_hdr_scroll.frame = CGRectMake
    }
    else 
    {
        m_data_tbl.frame = CGRectMake
        m_hdr_scroll.frame = CGRectMake
    }
    [m_data_tbl reloadData];
}
```

In portrait, the frame size is identical to the one is originally initialized with, and the data loaded does not get altered during the execution time; just whether the last two columns are displayed or not are different.

Not having done much iPhone development this issue is quite stumping me.

Comment: `setNeedsLayout` should call `[super setNeedsLayout]`, else you lose all of the default UIView functionality of setting needs layout. this may be causing your issue

Comment: Is it possible that your data source isn't fully loaded by the time that reloadData is called?